# changes to javascript effect the page layout

Tags: javascript

I have been asked by a friend to add a high score table to a game where you maneuver a snake that gets larger as it eats food. My friend wanted me to add a high score to the game.

here is the original code;

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simple Snake Game</title>

    <!-- Basic styling, centering of the canvas. -->
    <style>
    canvas {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        margin: auto;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var

/**
 * Constats
 */
COLS = 26,
ROWS = 26,

EMPTY = 0,
SNAKE = 1,
FRUIT = 2,

LEFT  = 0,
UP    = 1,
RIGHT = 2,
DOWN  = 3,

KEY_LEFT  = 37,
KEY_UP    = 38,
KEY_RIGHT = 39,
KEY_DOWN  = 40,


/**
 * Game objects
 */
canvas,   /* HTMLCanvas */
ctx,      /* CanvasRenderingContext2d */
keystate, /* Object, used for keyboard inputs */
frames,   /* number, used for animation */
score;    /* number, keep track of the player score */
high_score = [];


/**
 * Grid datastructor, usefull in games where the game world is
 * confined in absolute sized chunks of data or information.
 * 
 * @type {Object}
 */
grid = {

    width: null,  /* number, the number of columns */
    height: null, /* number, the number of rows */
    _grid: null,  /* Array<any>, data representation */

    /**
     * Initiate and fill a c x r grid with the value of d
     * @param  {any}    d default value to fill with
     * @param  {number} c number of columns
     * @param  {number} r number of rows
     */
    init: function(d, c, r) {
        this.width = c;
        this.height = r;

        this._grid = [];
        for (var x=0; x < c; x++) {
            this._grid.push([]);
            for (var y=0; y < r; y++) {
                this._grid[x].push(d);
            }
        }
    },

    /**
     * Set the value of the grid cell at (x, y)
     * 
     * @param {any}    val what to set
     * @param {number} x   the x-coordinate
     * @param {number} y   the y-coordinate
     */
    set: function(val, x, y) {
        this._grid[x][y] = val;
    },

    /**
     * Get the value of the cell at (x, y)
     * 
     * @param  {number} x the x-coordinate
     * @param  {number} y the y-coordinate
     * @return {any}   the value at the cell
     */
    get: function(x, y) {
        return this._grid[x][y];
    }
}

/**
 * The snake, works as a queue (FIFO, first in first out) of data
 * with all the current positions in the grid with the snake id
 * 
 * @type {Object}
 */
snake = {

    direction: null, /* number, the direction */
    last: null,      /* Object, pointer to the last element in
                        the queue */
    _queue: null,    /* Array<number>, data representation*/

    /**
     * Clears the queue and sets the start position and direction
     * 
     * @param  {number} d start direction
     * @param  {number} x start x-coordinate
     * @param  {number} y start y-coordinate
     */
    init: function(d, x, y) {
        this.direction = d;

        this._queue = [];
        this.insert(x, y);
    },

    /**
     * Adds an element to the queue
     * 
     * @param  {number} x x-coordinate
     * @param  {number} y y-coordinate
     */
    insert: function(x, y) {
        // unshift prepends an element to an array
        this._queue.unshift({x:x, y:y});
        this.last = this._queue[0];
    },

    /**
     * Removes and returns the first element in the queue.
     * 
     * @return {Object} the first element
     */
    remove: function() {
        // pop returns the last element of an array
        return this._queue.pop();
    }
};

/**
 * Set a food id at a random free cell in the grid
 */
function setFood() {
    var empty = [];
    // iterate through the grid and find all empty cells
    for (var x=0; x < grid.width; x++) {
        for (var y=0; y < grid.height; y++) {
            if (grid.get(x, y) === EMPTY) {
                empty.push({x:x, y:y});
            }
        }
    }
    // chooses a random cell
    var randpos = empty[Math.round(Math.random()*(empty.length - 1))];
    grid.set(FRUIT, randpos.x, randpos.y);
}

/**
 * Starts the game
 */
function main() {
    // create and initiate the canvas element
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = COLS*20;
    canvas.height = ROWS*20;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    // add the canvas element to the body of the document
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    // sets an base font for bigger score display
    ctx.font = "12px Helvetica";

    frames = 0;
    keystate = {};
    // keeps track of the keybourd input
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
        keystate[evt.keyCode] = true;
    });
    document.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
        delete keystate[evt.keyCode];
    });

    // intatiate game objects and starts the game loop
    init();
    loop();
}

/**
 * Resets and inits game objects
 */
function init() {
    score = 0;

    grid.init(EMPTY, COLS, ROWS);

    var sp = {x:Math.floor(COLS/2), y:ROWS-1};
    snake.init(UP, sp.x, sp.y);
    grid.set(SNAKE, sp.x, sp.y);

    setFood();
}

/**
 * The game loop function, used for game updates and rendering
 */
function loop() {
    update();
    draw();
    // When ready to redraw the canvas call the loop function
    // first. Runs about 60 frames a second
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
}

/**
 * Updates the game logic
 */
function update() {
    frames++;

    // changing direction of the snake depending on which keys
    // that are pressed
    if (keystate[KEY_LEFT] && snake.direction !== RIGHT) {
        snake.direction = LEFT;
    }
    if (keystate[KEY_UP] && snake.direction !== DOWN) {
        snake.direction = UP;
    }
    if (keystate[KEY_RIGHT] && snake.direction !== LEFT) {
        snake.direction = RIGHT;
    }
    if (keystate[KEY_DOWN] && snake.direction !== UP) {
        snake.direction = DOWN;
    }

    // each five frames update the game state.
    if (frames%5 === 0) {
        // pop the last element from the snake queue i.e. the
        // head
        var nx = snake.last.x;
        var ny = snake.last.y;

        // updates the position depending on the snake direction
        switch (snake.direction) {
            case LEFT:
                nx--;
                break;
            case UP:
                ny--;
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                nx++;
                break;
            case DOWN:
                ny++;
                break;
        }

        // checks all gameover conditions
        if (0 > nx || nx > grid.width-1  ||
            0 > ny || ny > grid.height-1 ||
            grid.get(nx, ny) === SNAKE
        ) {
            return init();
        }

        // check wheter the new position are on the fruit item
        if (grid.get(nx, ny) === FRUIT) {
            // increment the score and sets a new fruit position
            score++;
            setFood();
        } else {
            // take out the first item from the snake queue i.e
            // the tail and remove id from grid
            var tail = snake.remove();
            grid.set(EMPTY, tail.x, tail.y);
        }

        // add a snake id at the new position and append it to 
        // the snake queue
        grid.set(SNAKE, nx, ny);
        snake.insert(nx, ny);
    }
}

/**
 * Render the grid to the canvas.
 */
function draw() {
    // calculate tile-width and -height
    var tw = canvas.width/grid.width;
    var th = canvas.height/grid.height;
    // iterate through the grid and draw all cells
    for (var x=0; x < grid.width; x++) {
        for (var y=0; y < grid.height; y++) {
            // sets the fillstyle depending on the id of
            // each cell
            switch (grid.get(x, y)) {
                case EMPTY:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
                    break;
                case SNAKE:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#0ff";
                    break;
                case FRUIT:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
                    break;
            }
            ctx.fillRect(x*tw, y*th, tw, th);
        }
    }
    // changes the fillstyle once more and draws the score
    // message to the canvas
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillText("SCORE: " + score, 10, canvas.height-10);
}

// start and run the game
main();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDI: here is where I'm having problems

I added a high score variable here:

```
/**
 * Game objects
high_scores = []; // new code */
canvas,   /* HTMLCanvas */
ctx,      /* CanvasRenderingContext2d */
keystate, /* Object, used for keyboard inputs */
frames,   /* number, used for animation */
score,    /* number, keep track of the player score */
```

As well as here:

```
} else {
        // take out the first item from the snake queue i.e
        // the tail and remove id from grid
        var tail = snake.remove();
        grid.set(EMPTY, tail.x, tail.y);
        high_scores = high_scores.push(score)
    }
```

i don't get how a couple of javascript changes make the layout disappear. I've never coded in javascript that much and I dont understand why javaScript changes are affecting the layout.

Comment: Be more specific about what the exact changes are. There is a lot of code here for us to have to compare to figure it out. Also are any errors thrown?

Comment: https://www.diffchecker.com/1l5kizzx and there is no errors thrown in Google Chrome. I've only made two changes.

Comment: Please reduce your code down to only the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. there was an error in my syntax here

```
  /**
 * Game objects
 */
canvas,   /* HTMLCanvas */
ctx,      /* CanvasRenderingContext2d */
keystate, /* Object, used for keyboard inputs */
frames,   /* number, used for animation */
score,    /* number, keep track of the player score */
high_scores = [];
```